# EPPlus loses row height

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, templates, epplus

I have to use an existing excel and place contents on specific cells and give it to user through ASP.Net MVC site. The original excel should not be changed, so that it can be used as a template.
 The issue is though functionally everything works with EPPlus, the row heights of the original excel is completely lost in the resulting excel.

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(NewFile), new FileInfo(Template)))
         {
            ExcelWorksheet excelSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            //Do all process, mainly set specific cell values
            package.Save();
         }
         //Return the new file to user
```

Comment: Can you give more explanation on what you mean by the row heights are missing? Does the resulting excel file work? Can you maybe show some of the code where you're setting the values?

Comment: Have you looked at this discussion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739517/epplus-excel-row-height-not-consistent

Comment: I am having the same problem, after the code runs it completely changes the heights of the rows in the template, even though they are not addressed in any way (not a value inserted or style changed, nothing). Even worksheet.Row(i).Height stops working. At empty templates it is working ok - it keeps the rows the same height and worksheet.Row(i).Height is working ... 
I was wondering did you manage to find a solution ? @Persuader

Answer (score 0):

I always create a copy of my file first rather than opening any file that I want to remain unchanged.  I would try:

```
File.Copy(originalTemplate, workingTemplate, true);
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(NewFile), new FileInfo(workingTemplate)))
     {
        ExcelWorksheet excelSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        //Do all process, mainly set specific cell values
        package.Save();
     }
     //Return the new file to user
```