# EPPlus Excel Row Height not consistent

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have generated an excel file using EPPlus and everything seems to be perfect in MS Office 2007 but the client is using MS Office 2010/2013 and there the Row height is not set after the 29th Row.

It is a very weird issue and I have been trying to do this for 4 days but am not able to fix it.

I have attached an issue screenshot from excel.

```
List<spGetInventoryPrintForLabel> inventories = coreInventory.GetInventoryListForLabel(inventoryIDs);
                string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelLabelDocuments"), "Skyltar " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".xlsx");

                ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage();
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Blad1");
                ws.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ePaperSize.A4;
                ws.Cells["A:XFD"].Style.Font.Name = "Arial";
                ws.Cells["A:XFD"].Style.Font.Size = 10;
                ws.DefaultRowHeight = 16.5;
                ws.View.ShowGridLines = false;

                ws.Column(1).Width = ws.Column(3).Width = ws.Column(4).Width = ws.Column(6).Width = 4;
                ws.Column(2).Width = ws.Column(5).Width = 34.5;

                int sizeRowOfLabel = 10;
                int recordCount = 0;
                int labelStartIndex, rowIndex;
                labelStartIndex = rowIndex = 2;
                string column = "B";               

                using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/PrintLogo.jpg")))
                {
                    foreach (spGetInventoryPrintForLabel rw in inventories)
                    {
                        if (recordCount % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            column = "B";
                            ws.Cells["A" + labelStartIndex + ":C" + labelStartIndex].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                            ws.Cells["C" + labelStartIndex + ":C" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                            ws.Cells["A" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1) + ":C" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                            rowIndex = labelStartIndex;
                            if ((sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1) % 41 == 0)
                            {
                                ws.Row(sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1).PageBreak = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            column = "E";
                            ws.Cells["D" + labelStartIndex + ":F" + labelStartIndex].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                            ws.Cells["F" + labelStartIndex + ":F" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                            ws.Cells["D" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1) + ":F" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                            rowIndex = labelStartIndex;
                            labelStartIndex += sizeRowOfLabel;
                        }

                        //blank
                        rowIndex++;
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        //Artist
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = rw.ArtistName.Trim() == "," ? "" : rw.ArtistName; rowIndex++;
                        //Artist year (f. BirthYear) OR (BirthYear - DeathYear)
                        string artistBirth = string.Empty;
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtistDeath))
                            artistBirth = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtistBirth) ? "" : "f. " + rw.ArtistBirth);
                        else
                            artistBirth = rw.ArtistBirth + " - " + rw.ArtistDeath;
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = artistBirth; rowIndex++;
                        //blank
                        rowIndex++;
                        //Art title
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex + ":" + column + (rowIndex + 1)].Merge = true;
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.WrapText = true;
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = rw.ArtTitle + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.PurchaseYear) ? "" : ", " + rw.PurchaseYear); rowIndex++;
                        //blank
                        rowIndex++;
                        //Category
                        string category = string.Empty;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtTechnologyCategory))
                        {
                            category = rw.ArtTechnologyCategory;
                            category += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtSubCategory1)) ? "" : ", " + rw.ArtSubCategory1;
                            category += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtSubCategory2)) ? "" : ", " + rw.ArtSubCategory2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            category = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtSubCategory1)) ? "" : rw.ArtSubCategory1;
                            category += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtSubCategory2)) ? "" : ", " + rw.ArtSubCategory2;
                        }
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = category; rowIndex++;
                        //SK Number
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex + ":" + column + (rowIndex + 1)].Merge = true;
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
                        ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = rw.SKNumber; //rowIndex++;
                        //Logo
                        //ws.Cells[column + rowIndex + ":" + column + (rowIndex + 1)].Merge = true;
                        ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(rw.SKNumber, img);
                        pic.From.Column = column == "B" ? 1 : 4;
                        pic.From.Row = rowIndex - 1;
                        pic.From.ColumnOff = 160 * 9525;
                        pic.From.RowOff = 4 * 9525;
                        pic.SetSize(img.Width, img.Height);

                        recordCount++;
                    }
                }
```

[image: Row Height issue is highlighted]

Comment: I have seen this as well.  Since you have not assurance with how the file will be opened why not just set all row sizes manually in code?

Comment: Yes I have done that way also but it doesnt work.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 5):

What if you do something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 110; i++)
{
    ws.Row(i).Height = 20;
}
```

I threw your code in a quick unit test and it seemed to do the trick:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RowHeight_Test()
{
    var inventories = new List<RowObject>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        inventories.Add(new RowObject
        {
            ArtistName = "DOB - " + i,
            ArtSubCategory1 = "Cat 1 - " + i,
            ArtSubCategory2 = "Cat 2 - " + i,
            ArtTechnologyCategory = "Tech Cat - " + i,
            ArtTitle = "Title - " + i,
            ArtistBirth = "DOB - " + i,
            ArtistDeath = "DOD - " + i,
            PurchaseYear = "Year Purchased - " + i,
            SKNumber = "SKU Number - " + i,
        });
    }

    string fileName = "c:/temp/temp.xlsx";
    var newFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
    if (newFile.Exists)
        newFile.Delete();

    using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Blad1");
        ws.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ePaperSize.A4;
        ws.Cells["A:XFD"].Style.Font.Name = "Arial";
        ws.Cells["A:XFD"].Style.Font.Size = 10;
        ws.DefaultRowHeight = 16.5;
        ws.View.ShowGridLines = false;

        ws.Column(1).Width = ws.Column(3).Width = ws.Column(4).Width = ws.Column(6).Width = 4;
        ws.Column(2).Width = ws.Column(5).Width = 34.5;

        int sizeRowOfLabel = 10;
        int recordCount = 0;
        int labelStartIndex, rowIndex;
        labelStartIndex = rowIndex = 2;
        string column = "B";

        using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("c:/temp/logo.png"))
        {
            foreach (RowObject rw in inventories)
            {
                if (recordCount%2 == 0)
                {
                    column = "B";
                    ws.Cells["A" + labelStartIndex + ":C" + labelStartIndex].Style.Border.Top.Style =ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                    ws.Cells["C" + labelStartIndex + ":C" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                    ws.Cells[
                        "A" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1) + ":C" +
                        (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)].Style.Border.Bottom.Style =
                        ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                    rowIndex = labelStartIndex;
                    if ((sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)%41 == 0)
                    {
                        ws.Row(sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1).PageBreak = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    column = "E";
                    ws.Cells["D" + labelStartIndex + ":F" + labelStartIndex].Style.Border.Top.Style =ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                    ws.Cells["F" + labelStartIndex + ":F" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                    ws.Cells["D" + (sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1) + ":F" +(sizeRowOfLabel + labelStartIndex - 1)].Style.Border.Bottom.Style =ExcelBorderStyle.Dashed;
                    rowIndex = labelStartIndex;
                    labelStartIndex += sizeRowOfLabel;
                }

                //blank
                rowIndex++;
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                //Artist
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = rw.ArtistName.Trim() == "," ? "" : rw.ArtistName;
                rowIndex++;
                //Artist year (f. BirthYear) OR (BirthYear - DeathYear)
                string artistBirth = string.Empty;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtistDeath))
                    artistBirth = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtistBirth) ? "" : "f. " + rw.ArtistBirth);
                else
                    artistBirth = rw.ArtistBirth + " - " + rw.ArtistDeath;
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = artistBirth;
                rowIndex++;
                //blank
                rowIndex++;
                //Art title
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex + ":" + column + (rowIndex + 1)].Merge = true;
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.WrapText = true;
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = rw.ArtTitle +
                                                    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.PurchaseYear)
                                                        ? ""
                                                        : ", " + rw.PurchaseYear);
                rowIndex++;
                //blank
                rowIndex++;
                //Category
                string category = string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtTechnologyCategory))
                {
                    category = rw.ArtTechnologyCategory;
                    category += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtSubCategory1)) ? "" : ", " + rw.ArtSubCategory1;
                    category += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtSubCategory2)) ? "" : ", " + rw.ArtSubCategory2;
                }
                else
                {
                    category = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtSubCategory1)) ? "" : rw.ArtSubCategory1;
                    category += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.ArtSubCategory2)) ? "" : ", " + rw.ArtSubCategory2;
                }
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = category;
                rowIndex++;
                //SK Number
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex + ":" + column + (rowIndex + 1)].Merge = true;
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
                ws.Cells[column + rowIndex].Value = rw.SKNumber; //rowIndex++;
                //Logo
                //ws.Cells[column + rowIndex + ":" + column + (rowIndex + 1)].Merge = true;
                ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(rw.SKNumber, img);
                pic.From.Column = column == "B" ? 1 : 4;
                pic.From.Row = rowIndex - 1;
                pic.From.ColumnOff = 160*9525;
                pic.From.RowOff = 4*9525;
                pic.SetSize(img.Width, img.Height);

                recordCount++;
            }
        }

        for (var i = 1; i <= 110; i++)
        {
            ws.Row(i).Height = 20;
        }

        pack.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, ernie thanks for your reply. but i have tried to do this looping as well earlier this doesn't work.

Comment: @PrashantSarvaiya Thats interesting.  What happens when you run the unit test above?  Does it not work either?

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks.

Comment: Some time after, I have the same problem, I was just wondering if you have found a solution ? @Prashant Sarvaiya